# Proof algorithm to find representations as sum of two squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, sums-of-squares

I saw in a book the following algorithm to find, given a prime $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, integers $a $ and $b $ such that $p=a^2+b^2$.

**Step 1**  : Find an integer $0 <m  <p$ such that $m^2\equiv -1\pmod p$ (there is a clever method to do it but that's not the question here)

**Step 2** : Run the Euclidean algorithm with $p $ and $m $. Then the two first remainders which are less than $\sqrt p $ satisfy $r_1^2+r_2^2=p $.

I can't prove that the algorithm indeed works. I see that it suffices to prove that $r_1^2+r_2^2$ is divisible by $p $ but I don't see how to do it. Can you give me a hint ?

Comment: As for the first step you need to $a=2$ and do $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = -1 \mod p $ then $m = a^{\frac{p-1}{4}} \mod p$.

Comment: I know how to do the first step. And you are wrong, $2^{\frac  {p-1}{2 }} $ is not always $-1$ modulo $p $... It depends on $p \mod 8$.

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2323912?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents